# How to display first validation error in codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I need to get first error message in codeigniter form validation library.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with following code:

```
array_values($this->form_validation->error_array())[0]
```

Comment: this code will get break on the live server (especially if it's linux) instead do this: 
$error = $this->form_validation->error_array();
$arr    = $error[0];